# How to connect instances in different AWS accounts by private IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc-peering

Say I have accounts **A** and **B** and light sail instances **a** and **b** in each account. **a** and **b** are in the same region and zone. Is it possiple for **a** and **b** to interconnect with private IP? For example, after I log in to **a**, can I ssh to **b** using **b**'s private IP?

I searched documents and I think it's probably something related to VPC, but it's a little bit complicated to a new learner. Can anyone specify how to configure it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a VPN, assuming the subnets are different.

Answer (score 8):

It is called VPC Peering.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html

> A VPC peering connection is a networking connection between two VPCs
>   that enables you to route traffic between them using private IPv4
>   addresses or IPv6 addresses. Instances in either VPC can communicate
>   with each other as if they are within the same network. You can create
>   a VPC peering connection between your own VPCs, or with a VPC in
>   another AWS account. In both cases, the VPCs must be in the same
>   region.

Guide here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/

Comment: Specific link that addresses lightsail: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-lightsail-the-power-of-aws-the-simplicity-of-a-vps/

Comment: @dmourati you can only peer a Lightsail VPC to the *Default* VPC of the *same* AWS account.  Peering is not transitive, so Lightsail-to-Lightsail across accounts using VPC peering is not supported.

Comment: Not a lightsail user but OP did mention lightsail so I figured the above link would be relevant. Good to know the limitations of the simplified approach.